# Change the default SharePoint theme for anonymous users

Tags: anonymous-authentication, theme

How do I make a SharePoint site theme display correctly for anonymous users? 
I've added a link in the master page to the generated .css file but it is not working. Can anybody tell me why ?

Comment: Is the .css file (along with any related images, etc. required for the theme) checked in/published? If you attempt to navigate directly to the URLs of these files as an anonymous user, can you access them?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the theme files are checked in and publish in the major version.